# Parallel execution for Classes not working TestNG.xml file

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, testng, testng.xml

I'm stuck in running parallel execution. Need help & use-full thought.

My Driver class:

```
@Parameters({"environment","browser"})
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void startUp(String environment, String browser) {
    switch (browser) {
        case "firefox":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedirver";
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        default:
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    switch (environment) {
        case "fb":
            driver.get("https://facebook.com");
            break;
        case "yahoo":
            driver.get("https://yahoo.com");
            break;
        case "google":
            driver.get("https://google.com");
            break;
    }
```

Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Login Feature" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="fbe chrome" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="google"/>
        <classes><class name="framework.google.googlepage"></class></classes>
    </test>

    <test name="faceboo firefox">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="google"/>
        <classes><class name="framework.google.googlepage"></class></classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

I am using page object model and extending Driver Factory to Test Class
When I use `parallel= "classes" thread-count="2"`
it's run 1 after another class and in a different browser. [Not together/sametime]

When I use `parallel="tests" Thread-count= "2"`

Both browser open at the same time, 1 browser stop working and another browser does double click, double `sendkeys`. Work only 1 browser with both browser sets of data.

I want to run tests parallelly with a different browser same time.

Need help as my code is not working.

Comment: Those are included in xml file<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Login Feature" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

Comment: provide some more info.. how u trying to run tests? any one test case to see how u  r calling driver?

Comment: private static Webdriver driver =null;
  public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
TestCalss extend DriverFactory () {
@Test
public void testParallel(){
getDriver.findelement(By.Xpath("something")).click();
}
}
something like that
and Running using xml file,